# Who was the first married man to join the Night Watch while his wife was alive?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In G.Martin's books and series, who was the first married man about whom we know that he joined the Night Watch (by his own will, or being sentenced to do that) while his wife was alive?

Comment: It would be appropriate to correct the tag. Are you asking the answer for show or the books?

Comment: Good question, but seeing as the NW is 8,000 years old founded during the Age of Heroes and not much was written back then.

Comment: @NSNoob I would like to know examples from both books and series.

Comment: @Skooba I've added phrase "about whom we know"

Comment: @Schullz There is always Jeor Mormont. We however do not know about his wife, mother of Jorah Mormont. We do not know if she was alive when Jeor went to join the NW

Comment: @NSNoob I thought about Jeor, but I found nothing about his wife - was she alive or not. So, Jeor isn't an answer

Comment: I'd assume that joining the Watch would involve the marriage being nullified in some way, almost as if the man had died. The pledge says "I pledge my life and honor to the Night's Watch, for this night and all the nights to come." i.e. they'll ignore the past. If you lose your lands and your title, seems logical you'll also lose your family.

Comment: related, even though there is no answer... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128591/is-marriage-of-someone-swearing-to-celibacy-annulled-in-westeros

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes, that is a techincality in the question... The non-loop question may be, "Known member of the Nights Watch who had a wife before joining and that said previous wife was alive at the time the man joined"

Comment: Janos Slynt also had a son, but nothing's ever said about his wife.

Comment: People who took the black to avoid other forms of punishment for crimes they committed might have been married. So there may be a lot of them. But none are known or named.

Answer (score 2):

The first in terms of living people for the series was Mormont, who joined the knights watch after he had already had legitimate male son to take over from him as Lord of Bear Island.

The first is lost to history, although it would have almost certainly been a founding member of the knights watch after the "long night" after which the Knights watch was founded.

Comment: Was Mormont's wife alive when he joined NW?

Comment: There is no indication whether or not Mormont's wife was alive at that time. Mormont never discussed his wife nor did Jorah discuss his mother.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two examples that I can find but no explicit mention is made about a wife so we can't really know for sure.

#### Jeor Mormont

Jeor took the Black so his son, Jorah, could inherit Bear Island and become Lord Mormont. However, no mention is made to his wife and whether she was alive at that time.

> "It is," the Old Bear told him. "It was my father's sword, and his father's before him. The Mormonts have carried it for five centuries. I wielded it in my day and passed it on to my son when I took the black."
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Jon VIII</sub>

#### Janos Slynt

Again no mention is made to a wife but he does have true-born sons; the eldest of which is to become Lord Slynt. If he has true-born sons he must have had a wife at some point but it does not mention if she was alive at this time.

> "Dwarf?" His anger flashed. "You should have stopped at Imp. I am Tyrion of House Lannister, and someday, if you have the sense the gods gave a sea slug, you will drop to your knees in thanks that it was me you had to deal with, and not my lord father. Now, how many sons do you have?"
>   Tyrion could see the sudden fear in Janos Slynt's eyes. "Th-three, m'lord. And a daughter. Please, m'lord—"
>   "You need not beg." He slid off his chair. "You have my word, no harm will come to them. The younger boys will be fostered out as squires. If they serve well and loyally, they may be knights in time. Let it never be said that House Lannister does not reward those who serve it. Your eldest son will inherit the title Lord Slynt, and this appalling sigil of yours." He kicked at the little golden spear and sent it skittering across the floor. "Lands will be found for him, and he can build a seat for himself. It will not be Harrenhal, but it will be sufficient. It will be up to him to make a marriage for the girl."
>   <sub>A Clash of Kings, Tyrion II</sub>

Comment: As you note, there is no mention of their wives or their marital status at the time of their joining. If we are counting all the men who had children but then joined the Watch, I suspect it would be a rather long list. And why start at Mormont then? Start with the Dornish Kings Nymeria sent to the wall.

Comment: @Aegon Oh I know I just stated two likely examples. I didn't want to list every possible maybe.